# Run jQuery based on distance from bottom of window

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an element fade in when you reach the bottom of the screen, or thereabouts.

My problem at the moment is that the script only runs if you're absolutely at the last pixel on the screen. If you're, say, 3px up, then the animation won't show and you're left with a blank space.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $('#contact-form').css('opacity','1');
        }
    });
```

I want to make the animation start if you're `x` pixels away from the bottom. `x` will be determined by the height of a div. So:

```
var x = $('#contact-form').height();
```

How can I start my jQuery when the user scrolls to `x px away from bottom of page` ?

Comment: Instead of '$(document).height()', '$(document).height() - x'? That is if your x-div is at the bottom always.

Comment: @Mortaza have tried that but it does not seem to compute the result. Yes my div is always at the bottom. in the case of the above example, x = 466. But when I scroll to 466 away from the bottom it is not animating.

Comment: Try a > or a <, see the answer below me. When you scroll, it does not take into account EVERY pixel. If you are unsure, put a console.log() in so you can see the numbers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ThePendulum from #web here!

The distance scrolled from the top can be figured out with $(document).scrollTop(). To get the distance scrolled relative to the bottom of the document, you could substract the distance scrolled from the top of the document from the height of the document.

```
$(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop();
```

However, browsers stop scrolling as soon as the bottom of the viewframe hits the bottom of the document. You then only scrolled as far as the distance between the top of the document and the top of the viewframe.

To get the distance between the bottom of the document and the bottom of the viewframe, the height of the viewframe must be substracted from the distance scrolled as well.

```
Math.floor($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop() - $(window).height());
```

You can then simply check this value on scroll, and trigger whatever you wish to happen at a certain distance from the bottom.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var distanceFromBottom = Math.floor($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop() - $(window).height());

    if(distanceFromBottom < 200) {
        // We're less than 200 pixels away from the bottom!
    }
});
```

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ThePendulum/vwmh8o38/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to check if it's bigger than $(document).height()-x. Scroll events can jump numbers pretty fast, you'd have to be lucky to hit the number exactly. So this might do the trick:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - x) {
```