# SVG opacity change via scrollTop solved; now how do to add opacity change using "scrollBottom" in jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, scrolltop

A few weeks ago I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72775336/div-fade-in-onscroll-with-jquery-but-without-triggering-on-each-pixel) and received a [great answer from herrstrietzel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72901115/10422723). I've since decided that I want to fade my SVG out again based on distance from the bottom of the document, essentially a "scrollBottom":

`var distanceFromBottom = $(document).height() - ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height());`

I've taken [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30331660/10422723) for a similar scrollBottom question and adapted my code as follows below. At the moment, nothing is printing at all. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```js
let logo = $('.stickyMPlogo');

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var distanceFromBottom = $(document).height() - ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height());
  var scrollposition = $(this).scrollTop();
  let closed = logo.hasClass('closed');


  if ((distanceFromBottom < 400) && !closed) {
    logo.toggleClass('opened closed');
  } else if ((scrollposition < 800) && !closed) {
    logo.toggleClass('opened closed');
  } else if ((scrollposition > 800) && closed) {
    logo.toggleClass('closed opened');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.verticallogoFixed {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 80vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 2.25em;
  z-index: 700;
  margin: 0;
}

.stickyMPlogo {
  fill: #07372F;
  transition: 1s;
}

.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
}

.stickyMPlogo:hover {
  fill: #D5E900;
}

.svgLogo a {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0.1vw;
  padding-right: 0.1vw;
}

.closed {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.opened {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frame">

  <div class="verticallogoFixed">
    <a href="http://melanie-patterson.com/" class="svgLogo">
      <svg class="stickyMPlogo closed" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 1200" fill="#D5E900">
        <path d="M1.743 1096.853l68.161-32.474-68.16-25.37v-14.883h.845c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.665 7.78H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.508 22.664-7.78h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H4.534l75.602 28.076c-26.546 14.613-45.364 21.15-72.388 34.503l36.279.084c20.889.682 41.93-1.119 41.437-14.207h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.272-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.508-22.664 7.78h-.846zm0-77.804v-60.55H13.16v.846c-10.478-.7-11.12 29.485-10.571 44.65h36.364c-9.416-10.07.946-20.246 1.353-30.274 0-3.213-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.846c4.989 0 9.302 4.144 9.302 10.825 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.634a7.175 7.175 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.818 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.65v-.847H86.31v60.55h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm0-88.459h.846c0 7.274 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h60.211c-.498-10.964 2.456-42.495-13.108-44.566v-.845H86.31v60.465h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846zm32.22-76.533c-1.607 0-2.283.93-2.283 2.03 0 4.059 8.88 6.596 8.88 11.416 0 2.368-2.283 2.791-4.482 1.945L.052 855.833v-.846l71.459-27.061c9.302-3.721 13.953-6.427 13.953-11.585h.846v27.737h-.846c0-11.924-6.85-11.5-15.39-8.287L42.42 846.276c49.873-7.207 58.144 40.325 29.09 41.608-20.803 0-28.752-33.827-37.547-33.827zm49.979 13.361c-.622-20.07-31.318-23.743-47.103-19.027L9.862 858.623l25.877 9.726c2.96 1.099 3.975.422 3.975-.93 0-3.89-8.88-7.02-8.88-11.501 0-1.608 1.1-2.791 3.298-2.791 11.332 0 14.884 27.568 35.772 27.568 7.949 0 14.038-4.99 14.038-13.277zM1.743 799.002l72.22-47.357c-17.211.588-72.082-4.438-71.374 14.208h-.846v-22.834h.846c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h62.748c1.394 1.533-81.51 53.535-81.522 54.375 16.771-1.027 79.921 5.545 78.985-14.206h.846V813.8h-.846c0-7.274-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846zm0-61.059V715.11h.846c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.274-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm0-27.907v-60.55H13.16v.846c-10.478-.7-11.12 29.485-10.571 44.651h36.364c-9.416-10.07.947-20.247 1.353-30.274 0-3.214-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.846c4.989 0 9.302 4.143 9.302 10.824 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.635a7.175 7.175 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.818 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.651v-.846H86.31v60.55h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.508-22.664 7.78zm0-95.223c.59-12.335-1.283-22.719-1.692-35.265 1.257-46.321 70.636-32.988 49.05 20.296h13.7c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.845v22.749h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm49.64-32.897C49.89 545.64-13.2 551.842 3.944 599.844h44.312a48.422 48.422 0 0 0 3.129-17.928zm-17.42-59.198c-1.607 0-2.283.93-2.283 2.03 0 4.06 8.88 6.596 8.88 11.416 0 2.368-2.283 2.791-4.482 1.945L.052 524.494v-.846l71.459-27.061c9.302-3.72 13.953-6.427 13.953-11.586h.846v27.738h-.846c0-11.924-6.85-11.5-15.39-8.287L42.42 514.938c49.872-7.208 58.144 40.324 29.09 41.607-20.803 0-28.752-33.827-37.547-33.827zm49.979 13.361c-.622-20.07-31.318-23.743-47.103-19.027L9.862 527.284l25.877 9.726c2.96 1.099 3.975.422 3.975-.93 0-3.89-8.88-7.02-8.88-11.501 0-1.607 1.1-2.791 3.298-2.791 11.332 0 14.884 27.569 35.772 27.569 7.949 0 14.038-4.99 14.038-13.278zM1.743 434.344H13.16v.845c-6.041-.525-10.505 10.491-10.571 25.116h60.21c16.66 0 22.665.17 22.665-7.103h.846v22.072h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H2.59c.067 14.625 4.53 25.641 10.57 25.116v.845H1.744zm0-64.188H13.16v.846c-6.041-.525-10.505 10.49-10.571 25.116h60.21c16.66 0 22.665.17 22.665-7.104h.846v22.072h-.846c0-7.272-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H2.59c.067 14.626 4.53 25.642 10.57 25.117v.845H1.744zm0-5.076v-60.548H13.16v.845c-10.478-.699-11.12 29.486-10.571 44.651h36.364c-9.416-10.072.947-20.247 1.353-30.275 0-3.213-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.845c4.989 0 9.302 4.143 9.302 10.824 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.634a7.176 7.176 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.817 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.65v-.846H86.31v60.549h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm83.721-65.624c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846C2.332 287.12.461 276.739.051 264.192c-1.813-34.953 44.866-38.172 45.837-3.89-.001 7.949-5.413 13.361-5.413 16.913 0 1.015.254 2.452 2.198 2.452 5.497 0 6.681-17.843 17.337-24.693 10.401-6.68 25.454-14.545 25.454-24.186h.846c.051 20.223 3.24 13.081-25.37 32.558-12.347 8.203-12.685 17.167-18.435 17.167a2.722 2.722 0 0 1-2.876-2.96c0-4.99 4.82-8.88 4.82-16.744-2.227-27.942-56.286-24.068-40.507 23.678H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.846v22.748zM.052 192.9a70.913 70.913 0 0 1 3.89-24.1h11.332v.845S1.067 174.803 1.067 192.9c0 15.73 9.556 24.355 18.943 24.355 23.17 0 14.968-53.446 44.566-53.446 11.755 0 23.425 12.178 23.425 31.713 0 11.163-5.666 21.057-10.317 27.315H66.352c-.889-1.528 20.155-10.893 20.126-32.05 0-12.348-9.048-22.073-18.435-22.073-25.454 0-18.266 54.46-46.004 54.46C10.285 223.176.052 212.436.052 192.9zm43.975-39.24c-58.094-.207-58.089-75.063 0-75.264 58.094.206 58.088 75.062 0 75.263zm0-7.612c56.683-.588 56.678-59.456-.002-60.041-56.851-.33-56.846 60.376.002 60.041zM1.743 55.983l72.22-47.357C56.752 9.213 1.882 4.188 2.59 22.833h-.846V0h.846c0 7.272 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h62.748C89.392 9.309 6.494 61.318 6.48 62.156 23.251 61.129 86.4 67.7 85.464 47.949h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846z" />
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just so I'm clear and can better help you can I check are you wanting the image to start off faded out, fade in halfway down and then out and then finally back in at the end of the scroll ?

it seems to work better if you take the class has checked out, to help understand what's going I added so console.logging to give a meaningful read-out, you can use this to check the values at the time you wan it to be visible or not at given scroll position and adjust you if statements to match the values of the console log

```js
let logo = $('.stickyMPlogo');

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var distanceFromBottom = $(document).height() - ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height());
  var scrollposition = $(this).scrollTop();

  console.log(`
distanceFromBottom:${parseInt(distanceFromBottom)}, 
scrollposition:${parseInt(scrollposition)},
hasClosed:${logo.hasClass('closed')},
hasOpen:${logo.hasClass('opened')}`)
  if ((distanceFromBottom < 400)) {
    logo.toggleClass('opened closed');
  } else if ((scrollposition < 800)) {
    logo.toggleClass('opened closed');
  } else if ((scrollposition > 800)) {
    logo.toggleClass('closed opened');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.verticallogoFixed {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 80vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 2.25em;
  z-index: 700;
  margin: 0;
}

.stickyMPlogo {
  fill: #07372F;
  transition: 1s;
}

.verticallogoFixed .stickyMPlogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
}

.stickyMPlogo:hover {
  fill: #D5E900;
}

.svgLogo a {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0.1vw;
  padding-right: 0.1vw;
}

.closed {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.opened {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frame">

  <div class="verticallogoFixed">
    <a href="http://melanie-patterson.com/" class="svgLogo">
      <svg class="stickyMPlogo closed" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 1200" fill="#D5E900">
        <path d="M1.743 1096.853l68.161-32.474-68.16-25.37v-14.883h.845c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.665 7.78H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.508 22.664-7.78h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H4.534l75.602 28.076c-26.546 14.613-45.364 21.15-72.388 34.503l36.279.084c20.889.682 41.93-1.119 41.437-14.207h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.272-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.508-22.664 7.78h-.846zm0-77.804v-60.55H13.16v.846c-10.478-.7-11.12 29.485-10.571 44.65h36.364c-9.416-10.07.946-20.246 1.353-30.274 0-3.213-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.846c4.989 0 9.302 4.144 9.302 10.825 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.634a7.175 7.175 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.818 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.65v-.847H86.31v60.55h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm0-88.459h.846c0 7.274 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h60.211c-.498-10.964 2.456-42.495-13.108-44.566v-.845H86.31v60.465h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846zm32.22-76.533c-1.607 0-2.283.93-2.283 2.03 0 4.059 8.88 6.596 8.88 11.416 0 2.368-2.283 2.791-4.482 1.945L.052 855.833v-.846l71.459-27.061c9.302-3.721 13.953-6.427 13.953-11.585h.846v27.737h-.846c0-11.924-6.85-11.5-15.39-8.287L42.42 846.276c49.873-7.207 58.144 40.325 29.09 41.608-20.803 0-28.752-33.827-37.547-33.827zm49.979 13.361c-.622-20.07-31.318-23.743-47.103-19.027L9.862 858.623l25.877 9.726c2.96 1.099 3.975.422 3.975-.93 0-3.89-8.88-7.02-8.88-11.501 0-1.608 1.1-2.791 3.298-2.791 11.332 0 14.884 27.568 35.772 27.568 7.949 0 14.038-4.99 14.038-13.277zM1.743 799.002l72.22-47.357c-17.211.588-72.082-4.438-71.374 14.208h-.846v-22.834h.846c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h62.748c1.394 1.533-81.51 53.535-81.522 54.375 16.771-1.027 79.921 5.545 78.985-14.206h.846V813.8h-.846c0-7.274-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846zm0-61.059V715.11h.846c0 7.273 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.274-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm0-27.907v-60.55H13.16v.846c-10.478-.7-11.12 29.485-10.571 44.651h36.364c-9.416-10.07.947-20.247 1.353-30.274 0-3.214-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.846c4.989 0 9.302 4.143 9.302 10.824 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.635a7.175 7.175 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.818 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.651v-.846H86.31v60.55h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.508-22.664 7.78zm0-95.223c.59-12.335-1.283-22.719-1.692-35.265 1.257-46.321 70.636-32.988 49.05 20.296h13.7c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.845v22.749h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm49.64-32.897C49.89 545.64-13.2 551.842 3.944 599.844h44.312a48.422 48.422 0 0 0 3.129-17.928zm-17.42-59.198c-1.607 0-2.283.93-2.283 2.03 0 4.06 8.88 6.596 8.88 11.416 0 2.368-2.283 2.791-4.482 1.945L.052 524.494v-.846l71.459-27.061c9.302-3.72 13.953-6.427 13.953-11.586h.846v27.738h-.846c0-11.924-6.85-11.5-15.39-8.287L42.42 514.938c49.872-7.208 58.144 40.324 29.09 41.607-20.803 0-28.752-33.827-37.547-33.827zm49.979 13.361c-.622-20.07-31.318-23.743-47.103-19.027L9.862 527.284l25.877 9.726c2.96 1.099 3.975.422 3.975-.93 0-3.89-8.88-7.02-8.88-11.501 0-1.607 1.1-2.791 3.298-2.791 11.332 0 14.884 27.569 35.772 27.569 7.949 0 14.038-4.99 14.038-13.278zM1.743 434.344H13.16v.845c-6.041-.525-10.505 10.491-10.571 25.116h60.21c16.66 0 22.665.17 22.665-7.103h.846v22.072h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H2.59c.067 14.625 4.53 25.641 10.57 25.116v.845H1.744zm0-64.188H13.16v.846c-6.041-.525-10.505 10.49-10.571 25.116h60.21c16.66 0 22.665.17 22.665-7.104h.846v22.072h-.846c0-7.272-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H2.59c.067 14.626 4.53 25.642 10.57 25.117v.845H1.744zm0-5.076v-60.548H13.16v.845c-10.478-.699-11.12 29.486-10.571 44.651h36.364c-9.416-10.072.947-20.247 1.353-30.275 0-3.213-1.861-6.258-4.82-6.258v-.845c4.989 0 9.302 4.143 9.302 10.824 0 10.317-7.273 14.63-7.442 20.634a7.176 7.176 0 0 0 2.96 5.92h45.158c-.446-10.817 2.366-42.783-13.108-44.65v-.846H86.31v60.549h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78zm83.721-65.624c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846C2.332 287.12.461 276.739.051 264.192c-1.813-34.953 44.866-38.172 45.837-3.89-.001 7.949-5.413 13.361-5.413 16.913 0 1.015.254 2.452 2.198 2.452 5.497 0 6.681-17.843 17.337-24.693 10.401-6.68 25.454-14.545 25.454-24.186h.846c.051 20.223 3.24 13.081-25.37 32.558-12.347 8.203-12.685 17.167-18.435 17.167a2.722 2.722 0 0 1-2.876-2.96c0-4.99 4.82-8.88 4.82-16.744-2.227-27.942-56.286-24.068-40.507 23.678H62.8c16.66 0 22.664-.507 22.664-7.78h.846v22.748zM.052 192.9a70.913 70.913 0 0 1 3.89-24.1h11.332v.845S1.067 174.803 1.067 192.9c0 15.73 9.556 24.355 18.943 24.355 23.17 0 14.968-53.446 44.566-53.446 11.755 0 23.425 12.178 23.425 31.713 0 11.163-5.666 21.057-10.317 27.315H66.352c-.889-1.528 20.155-10.893 20.126-32.05 0-12.348-9.048-22.073-18.435-22.073-25.454 0-18.266 54.46-46.004 54.46C10.285 223.176.052 212.436.052 192.9zm43.975-39.24c-58.094-.207-58.089-75.063 0-75.264 58.094.206 58.088 75.062 0 75.263zm0-7.612c56.683-.588 56.678-59.456-.002-60.041-56.851-.33-56.846 60.376.002 60.041zM1.743 55.983l72.22-47.357C56.752 9.213 1.882 4.188 2.59 22.833h-.846V0h.846c0 7.272 6.005 7.78 22.664 7.78h62.748C89.392 9.309 6.494 61.318 6.48 62.156 23.251 61.129 86.4 67.7 85.464 47.949h.846v22.833h-.846c0-7.273-6.004-7.78-22.664-7.78H25.253c-16.66 0-22.664.507-22.664 7.78h-.846z" />
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickHume/2a8odh4e/1/

I hope this helps

Comment: Thins looks really good, thank you! It does seem to flicker a lot unfortunately. The 0% opacity change with a scrollposition < 800 isn't always consistent....if I scroll back up, it is sometimes still at 100% opacity.

I'm looking for scrollposition < 800 = 0% opacity (starts at 0)
scrollposition > 800 =  100% opacity
and then 0% opacity again just before the bottom (< 400) of the document.

Comment: Ah, I've got it now. Your answer was a huge help, thanks a ton. I had to add the class checks back in. The problem with scrollTop (scrollposition, here) is that it triggers repeatedly on every single pixel. That's why the class check is important, so that at the right position from the top/bottom, it only triggers if the class is opposite of what it needs to be. I also added `distancefrombottom === 0` and a class toggle of 'closed closed', which that stops the flickering at the bottom.

Comment: ah cool glad you were able to work it out and that i was able to help a bit =)